# Post carrier to Bigcommerce Shipments API

Tags: bigcommerce

When an item ships via FedEx I want the end customer to see a FedEx tracking number. How do I indicate the carrier? Do I put "FedEx" in the shipping_method field?

Answer (score 1):

The shipping carrier can only be set during the initial POST and not with subsequent PUT requests. When creating a shipment and you want to denote the shipping carrier, you should send a POST request with a json body such as:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "order_id": 115,
    "customer_id": 0,
    "order_address_id": 16,
    "date_created": "Wed, 19 Dec 2012 17:17:10 +0000",
    "tracking_number": "111222333444",
    "shipping_method": "None",
    "shipping_provider": "fedex",
    "tracking_carrier": "fedex",
    "comments": "A sample shipment for order 115",
    "billing_address": {
      "first_name": "Louise",
      "last_name": "Dean",
      "company": "Skiptube",
      "street_1": "147 Meadow Vale Way",
      "street_2": "",
      "city": "Fullerton",
      "state": "Rhode Island",
      "zip": "74674",
      "country": "United States",
      "country_iso2": "US",
      "phone": "7-(086)085-9448",
      "email": ""
    },
    "shipping_address": {
      "first_name": "Louise",
      "last_name": "Dean",
      "company": "Skiptube",
      "street_1": "147 Meadow Vale Way",
      "street_2": "",
      "city": "Fullerton",
      "state": "Rhode Island",
      "zip": "74674",
      "country": "United States",
      "country_iso2": "US",
      "phone": "7-(086)085-9448",
      "email": ""
    },
    "items": [
      {
        "order_product_id": 16,
        "product_id": 0,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "shipping_method" is the correct property to use for the carrier name.