# How do I link a tracking number to a specific carrier in Bigcommerce?

Tags: api, bigcommerce

Through the Bigcommerce API I am trying to upload the carrier along with the tracking number so that the tracking number links to a carriers website. Following the instructions here - [Post carrier to Bigcommerce Shipments API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017286/post-carrier-to-bigcommerce-shipments-api?rq=1) - I set the shipping_method to UPS. However, when looking at the shipment information in the Bigcommerce backend, shipping method shows - Other(UPS). Also, the tracking number is not linked to any website.

How do I properly set shipping_method so that it won't be prefixed with Other and the tracking number is linked to that carrier?

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the Shipments API resource. Shipments created via the API always prefix the shipping_methods property with "Other" and do not link the tracking number to the appropriate carrier website. Shipments need to be created via the Control Panel for the tracking number URL to behave as you're describing.

Comment: I was actually able to upload a shipping method through the API without it getting prefixed with Other. It seems to me that the prefix and associated carrier website comes from the shipping method that the customer requests. In my first few test orders, I made the orders manually on the Bigcommerce backend and didn't select a shipping method. But when I placed an order on the stores front end and selected a shipping method, that carrier is what shipping_method got prefixed with. The tracking number was then also linked to the appropriate website.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. I was only thinking of manual orders with shipments created via the API.

Answer (score 1):

So I did some playing around and it seems that the tracking numbers associated website and the prefix comes from the requested shipping. My first couple of orders were created manually and I did not select a shipping method. However, when I placed an order on the stores frontend and selected a shipping method, shipping_method was then prefixed with the requested carrier. This also happened when I created a manual order in the backend and actually selected a shipping method.

Long story short, it appears to me that the website linked to the tracking number, is associated with the shipping method that the customer selected.